# Get authenticated user

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, oauth

I'm implementing a project using Spring security oauth2, everything works perfectly, now I want to start digging deeper beyond the basics. I want to check if the user making the request is the actual user owner of the resource, the end result would be for example:

> /private/users/{uuid}/clients  returns all clients for the specified user.

So my controller now looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "Hello world";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/private")
    public String privateTest(Principal principal) {
        User user = userService.get(principal.getName());
        return user.getUuid();
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** The full security code (working) for a better explanation.

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/home","/register","/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/private/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

**CustomUserDetails** with getters and setters off course

```
 public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private String password;
    private String username;
    private String uuid;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.uuid = user.getUuid();
        this.authorities = translate(user.getRoles());
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT").scopes("read","write","trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource").accessTokenValiditySeconds(5000).secret("secret");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }   
}
```

**Main**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DummyOauthApplication {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DummyOauthApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder, UserRepository repository, UserService service) throws Exception {
        //Setup a default user if db is empty
        if (repository.count() == 0) {
            service.save(new User("user", "password", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), Arrays.asList(new Role("USER"), new Role("ACTUATOR"))));
        }
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService(repository)).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService(final UserRepository repository) {
        return username -> new CustomUserDetails(repository.findByUsername(username));
    }
}
```

So, using the way I've implemented. I can get the actual user but it implies a database query every time an endpoint is called. Getting the user and match with the user uuid.

I want to find another way that I can get the user and then compare if the uuid = user.getUuid()

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time and a lot of mistakes, I've managed to find a solution that I leave here. The CustomUserDetails can be seen in the question and from there you can easily get the uuid and match with the requested one.

```
public static CustomUserDetails getCurrentUser() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    if (authentication != null) {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof CustomUserDetails) {
            return (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("User not found!");
}
```

**EDIT:** if you want to return the user you do something like this

```
    public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private String password;
    private String username;
    private User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.user = user;
        this.authorities = translate(user.getRoles());
    }
}
```

And then in a Utils or something,

```
public static User getCurrentUser() {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof CustomUserDetails) {
                 CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
                return userDetails.getUser();
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("User not found!");
    }
```

Thanks for all the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could implement a custom *AuthenticationProvider* and store  user details as *Principal*

[Spring Security Authentication Provider](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider)

Comment: I've just tried but I'm having problems in integration. I've updated my post to clarify the reader regarding my implementation till now. Thanks for your time.